# I need an exam of complete undergraduate mathematics courses.

Tags: advice, online-resources

I have an important exam in which I am responsible for undergraduate level of
Calculus, Advanced Calculus, Linear Algebra, Differential Equations, Abstract Algebra and Real Analysis.

Do you know any kind of exams measuring general knowledge on these topics? Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a qualifying exam. Did your school provide samples?

Comment: Standford has some: https://mathematics.stanford.edu/academicsgraduate-students/phd-program/phd-qualifying-exams

Comment: @DavidP I'm not sure that the Stanford Qualifying exams are appropriate. They assume you've taken first year graduate classes--it sounds like the OP is talking about undergraduate material.

Answer (score 2):

One of the exams students write for a graduate admissions in North America is the GRE Mathematics Subject Test (although more and more schools are no longer requiring such standardized tests). It covers roughly the topics you mention in a single exam. Here is an official "practice book" for GRE exam with many questions for practice:

https://www.ets.org/content/dam/ets-org/pdfs/gre/practice-book-math.pdf

Additional problem sets can be found here:

[https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/)

For example, check out

[https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/files/week1.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/files/week1.pdf)

to see if the problems are at an appropriate difficulty level for your upcoming exam.

Comment: These are more basic than average undergraduate level